View Hierarchy Not Capturing Location Authorization Prompt
Why does the view hierarchy NOT capture the location authorization prompt?


Because the view hierarchy shows only your app. The authorization prompt is not part of your app; it is imposed by the runtime, using a window that appears in front of yours and doesn't belong to you.

Is this a bad question? Why getting marked down

How is that a valid comment on my answer?

i gave an upvote on the answer. thought you gave downvote on question. anyway all good

(1) If my answer is correct and helped you, the way to respond is to accept my answer, thus closing out this question/answer pair. (2) Votes on questions, answers, etc. are anonymous. There is no point talking about them, because you have no way of talking to the "right" person.
